# How to customize ArrangeAll action or is it better to wright our own

Tags: java, emf, eclipse-gmf

After an import of project from an ASCII file, the later is transformed into nodes and connections inside a graphical Diagram, after sending the ArrangeALL request and executing the action, the diagram seems to arrange all Blocks first left to right by rising index and then corresponding inputs and outputs. 
Final result [see Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsV4p.png)makes understanding the program impossible.

How can i bring modification to the Action or is it better to implement our own arrange algorithm to fulfill our goal ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Sirius or gmf?

Comment: I am using gmf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ELK plugin to perform various layout operations.

About Eclipse Layout Kernel (ELK): it provides a number of layout algorithms as well as an Eclipse-based infrastructure to connect them to editors and viewers.

You can go through the [Getting Started Guide](https://www.eclipse.org/elk/gettingstarted.html) to learn about the same more.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/elk/tree/master/plugins/org.eclipse.elk.conn.gmf in this link are the implementations needed for elk use in gmf, how do i attach it to my editor is it through an extension point ?